# Scanf - varaible per reference VS parameter per reference

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, scanf, pass-by-value

I have a little knot in my head. I was just trying to explain to someone, why a little program uses pointers the way it does, and then she asked me about a different way, which should (to my knowledge) work, but doesn't.
Here's the code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputNums(double *valOne, double *secVal)
{
    printf("Enter your first number: ");
    scanf("%lf", valOne);

    printf("Enter your second number: ");
    scanf("%lf", secVal);
}

void sum(double valOne, double secVal )
{
    double result = valOne + secVal;
    printf("The sum is: %.2f\n", result);
}


int main()
{
    double numOne;
    double numTwo;

    inputNums(&numOne, &numTwo);
    sum(numOne, numTwo);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the code that doesn't, but I don't get why:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputNums(double valOne, double secVal)
{
    printf("Enter your first number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &valOne);

    printf("Enter your second number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &secVal);
}

void sum(double valOne, double secVal )
{
    double result = valOne + secVal;
    printf("The sum is: %.2f\n", result);
}


int main()
{
    double numOne;
    double numTwo;

    inputNums(numOne, numTwo);
    sum(numOne, numTwo);
    return 0;
}
```

I know it's something really simple, but for the love of god, I can't figure it out. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two function calls happening in your code that need to be able to modify the data in the caller:

- The call of `inputNums(...)`, and
- The call of `scanf(...)`, which happens from inside `inputNums(...)`

In order for the nested call of `scanf` to be able to modify data in `main`, `scanf` needs to have a pointer to the data in the `main`: that's the only way a C function can modify a local variable inside its caller.

In your first example `inputNums` has a pointer to variables inside `main` so the modification works fine, while in the second example it does not have a pointer to variables of `main`, because you pass parameters by value. That is what breaks your second implementation.

Here is an illustration of what is happening:

[image: Passing by pointer vs. passing by value]

In the first case pointers to `numOne` and `numTwo` of `main` are passed all the way to `scanf`, while in the second case `scanf` sees pointers to local `valOne` and `secVal` of `inputNums`, which is what it modifies, without touching the variables of `main`.

Comment: Does it matter that scanf() is a nested function, or would a simple manipulation of &double in the inputNums() break it too?

Comment: @BigBadWolf I added an illustration to show what is happening. Passing a pointer to variables inside `main` can be broken at each level that touches the pointer. In order for the code to work, the function that ultimately performs the modification (in this case that's `scanf`) has to have the pointer to the variable being modified.

Answer (score 1):

It`s pretty simple, all values in C are passed by value by default.

Which makes your inputNums only modify a copy of your variables.

And in that example your variable are the adresses of your numOne and numTwo

With that statement
    `inputNums(&numOne, &numTwo);`

your are only sending a copy of the address of numOne and numTwo
    which would be some address on your main stack.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because C is pass-by-value. In the second block of code,

```
void inputNums(double valOne, double secVal)
{
```

The **values** of valOne and secVal are passed in, whereupon they become local variables. Your pointer code is changing those variables correctly, but they're still deleted when the function returns because the variables are local.

In the first block,

```
void inputNums(double *valOne, double *secVal)
{
```

the only values passed in are the addresses of two variables that are in the scope of the main method (that is, the variables numOne and numTwo); following those pointers leads to those variables and the changes stick when the function returns.

Comment: Alright, thanks, it really was something simple. I kind of thought that the gcc simply replaces void functions with their content, unlike nonvoid functions.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example,you are doing [pass-by-reference](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/catam/ccatsl/manual/node50.html) while in the second one,it is [pass-by-value](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/catam/ccatsl/manual/node50.html).

In the first example,you are passing the address of the variables `numOne` and `numTwo` to the function `inputNums` and the parameters for that function are pointers. This means that those two pointers,`valOne` and `secVal` hold the address of the variables in `numOne` and `numTwo`. So modifying `*valOne` and `*secVal`(the values stored in the address that the two pointers hold) **will** modify the value of the variables in `main`(`numOne` and `numTwo`).

In the second example,you pass the values of `numOne` and `numTwo` to the funcion `inputNums` and hence,a copy of the varaibles is made and the initial values stored in `numOne` and `numTwo` are copied to the variables `valOne` and `secVal` in the function `inputNums`. Modifying these variables **will not** modify the values of `numOne` and `numTwo` as all these variables are stored in different memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, `inputNums` takes its arguments by value. Thus, the changes made there don't affect the variables in `main`. `valOne` in `inputNums` is a copy of `numOne`. OTOH, in the first example, since `inputNums` had pointer arguments, the changes you were making was to the variables that they were pointing to. `valOne`, in that case, was pointing to `numOne` and the `scanf` call modified `numOne`.